# Решение задачи acmp.ru на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Совсем недавно Вася занялся программированием и решил реализовать собственную программу для игры в шахматы. Но у него возникла проблема определения правильности хода конем, который делает пользователь. Т.е. если пользователь вводит значение «C7-D5», то программа должна определить это как правильный ход, если же введено «E2-E4», то ход неверный. Так же нужно проверить корректность записи ввода: если например, введено «D9-N5», то программа должна определить данную запись как ошибочную. Помогите ему осуществить эту проверку!
>
> Входные данные
>   В единственной строке входного файла INPUT.TXT записан текст хода (непустая строка), который указал пользователь. Пользователь не может ввести строку, длиннее 5 символов.
>
> Выходные данные
>   В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT нужно вывести «YES», если указанный ход конем верный, если же запись корректна (в смысле правильности записи координат), но ход невозможен, то нужно вывести «NO». Если же координаты не определены или заданы некорректно, то вывести сообщение «ERROR».

Код составил такой, но он не проходит даже 1 теста, в чем ошибка?

```
import re
i=open('input.txt')
o=open('output.txt', 'w')
x=''
j=i.read()
m=re.fullmatch(r'[A-H][1-8]-[A-H][1-8]', j)
if m:
    if j=='C7-D5':
            x='YES'
    else:
        x='NO'
else:
    x='ERROR'
o.write(x)
i.close()
o.close()
```

[image: Изображение к задаче][image: застревает на 1]

Comment: Прям вообще-вообще ни одного? А сам acmp.ru что-нибудь по этому поводу пишет? Тесты просто не проходят или возникает ошибка выполнения? Питон точно третий на acmp.ru?

Comment: В acmp Python 3.6

Comment: Застревает на самом первом тесте. Даже время не выводит

Comment: Если работа прерывается сразу после первого теста, то остаётся только посоветовать писать сразу полноценное решение, а не заглушку как у вас. Кстати применяйте strip() к входной строке, чтобы отсечь символ переноса строки, если вдруг он в тестах есть

Comment: Извиняюсь, в каком смысле полноценное решение и почему код "заглушка"?

Comment: Вы умеете играть в шахматы? :) C7-D5 это не единственный возможный ход коня

Comment: Аааааа, спасибо, теперь понял. Попробую

Comment: Думал, что верен только ход когда конь срубает другого

Comment: Конь в данной задаче стоит в любом месте на пустой доске, верен любой ход буквой Г в пределах доски (точное место и ход даны во входных данных)

Comment: Да уже понял, спасибо:) Всё таки играл в шахматы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def check(move):
    if len(move) != 5:
        return 'ERROR'

    ch = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5, 'F': 6, 'G': 7, 'H': 8}
    src, dst = move.split('-')

    if all([int(src[1]) % 9, int(dst[1]) % 9]):
        try:
            result = '{0}{1}'.format(
                abs(ch[src[0]] - ch[dst[0]]), 
                abs(int(src[1]) - int(dst[1]))
            )
            if result in ('12', '21'):
                return 'YES'

            return 'NO'

        except KeyError:
            return 'ERROR'

    return 'ERROR'


print(check('C7-D5'))  # YES
print(check('E2-E4'))  # NO
print(check('D9-N5'))  # ERROR
print(check('D4-F3'))  # YES
```

**UPD**: данное решение проходит проверку

```
def check(move):
    if len(move) != 5:
        return 'ERROR'
    ch = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5, 'F': 6, 'G': 7, 'H': 8}
    try:
        src, dst = move.split('-')
        if all([int(src[1]) % 9, int(dst[1]) % 9]):
            try:
                result = '{0}{1}'.format(abs(ch[src[0]] - ch[dst[0]]), abs(int(src[1]) - int(dst[1])))
                if result in ('12', '21'):
                    return 'YES'
                return 'NO'
            except KeyError:
                return 'ERROR'
        return 'ERROR'
    except ValueError:
        return 'ERROR'

with open('INPUT.TXT', 'r') as fin:
    with open('OUTPUT.TXT', 'w') as fout:
        fout.write(check(fin.readline()[:-1]))
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>                        start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)                              File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start                           exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)         File "<string>", line 27, in <module>                       File "<string>", line 8, in check TypeError: all() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: @Xenium `[]` квадратные скобки внутри `all([ ... ])` нужны, исправил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, но увы с этим кодом та же история(open и write дописал) в консоли работает а на сайте нет

Comment: @Xenium добавил решение, которое прошло все тесты

Comment: Спасибо большое. Теперь понял что не могу реализовать даже части всех возможностей языка

Answer (score 0):

Вы серьёзно проверяете `if j=='C7-D5':` ?

А логика должна быть такая:

- допустимые клетки - это уже сделано
- выделить из входной строки координаты начальной и конечной клетки
- модули разницы по вертикали и по горизонтали должны быть 1 или 2
- эти модули между собой не равны.

Попробуйте это выразить в коде.

Comment: Думаю, автор просто просто пробует загрузить хоть что-нибудь для тестирования. Такой код обязан пройти хотя бы пару тестов чисто по случайности. И непрохождение ни одного теста — это весьма странно

Comment: Думаете, тест 'C7-D5' обязан попасться?

Comment: Думаю, обязан попасться хотя бы тест на ERROR, который вроде бы должен проходить

Comment: А тесты проходятся пачкой (3 passed 1 failed) или друг за другом (т.е. если первый же не удался - до свидания) ?

Comment: Примерно это я спросил у автора в комментарии) Но по-моему в подобных проверках они обычно проходятся пачкой

Comment: Именно этот код. Останавливается на 1

Comment: Код не очень, согласен. Сам Python начал изучать буквально 2 недели назад

Comment: Ну дело пока не в питоне, а в неверной логической предпосылке.